# Getting 'change you requested was rejected "422"' while using Git Hooks to trigger the pipeline

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline, cicd

I'm trying to trigger a pipeline with git-hooks. I've set a custom_hooks [post-receive] inside the git repository. Gitlab is running on the docker container.

When I'm pushing the code, according to my hook logic it must check if the branch is main from the refs then it should trigger the build.

```
#!/bin/bash

if ! [ -t 0 ]; then
        read -a ref
fi

echo "running"

IFS='/' read -ra REF <<< "${ref[2]}"
branch="${REF[2]}"

if [ $branch == "main" ]; then
        curl -v -X POST http://my-jenkins-cicd:8080/job/react-pipeline/build?delay=0sec --user <my-jenkins-user>:<my-jenkins-API-token>

        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                echo "*** Ok"
        else
                echo "*** Error"
        fi

fi
```

So, when I'm pushing the code, post-receive is getting executed & gives the below error:

```
remote: > 
remote:   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0<!DOCTYPE html>
remote: <html>
remote: <head>
remote:   <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" name="viewport">
remote:   <title>The change you requested was rejected (422)</title>
remote:   <style>
......
remote:     <h3>The change you requested was rejected.</h3>
remote:     <hr />
remote:     <p>Make sure you have access to the thing you tried to change.</p>
remote:     <p>Please contact your GitLab administrator if you think this is a mistake.</p>
remote:     <a href="javascript:history.back()" class="js-go-back go-back">Go back</a>
......
remote: < HTTP/1.0 422 Unprocessable Content
remote: < Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
remote: < X-Runtime: 0.444229
remote: < X-Gitlab-Meta: {"correlation_id":"cf244e4b-f19a-44a5-adcf-18b2cb1bb8dd","version":"1"}
remote: < X-Request-Id: cf244e4b-f19a-44a5-adcf-18b2cb1bb8dd
remote: < Content-Length: 3035
remote: < 
remote: { [3035 bytes data]
remote: 100  3035  100  3035    0     0   5861      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  5859
remote: * Closing connection 0
remote: *** Ok -> the //'*** OK' from my post-receive hook
```

Meanwhile, If I run the build manually from Jenkins then it gets successfully built. I've also tried to build with running the curl command manually it also smoothly triggers the buid.
I've given `git:git user:group` to the file plus also gave the executable permissions `'chmod +x ...'`

The code is on the gitlab repository which is running on the docker container, I've not generated any API token from the gitlab since my build get successfully trigger on manual execution & get deploys on the K8s.

So, is there anything further I need to do?

Gitlab docker container:

```
version: '3'
services:
  git:
    container_name: git-server
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
    hostname: 'gitlab.example.com'
    ports:
      - '8090:80'
    volumes:
      - '/srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab'
      - '/srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
      - '/srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
    networks:
      - net
networks:
  net:
```

pushing the code on 8090.